# Traveling sales man with alternating groups of destinations.

Tags: optimization, hamiltonian-path

I am looking for an algorithm to determine the best route where the groups of destinations alternate.

For example: I have three stores and three warehouses. So I would like to visit a warehouse first, then a store, then a warehouse, then a store and so on. What are some algorithms for finding the best route in these circumstances.

Parameters and Restrictions:

- Equal number of Warehouse and Stores.
- Each location only visited once.

Comment: Just run a standard traveling salesman algorithm, setting the distances between stores to infinity (meaning: to such a large number that no self-respecting traveling salesman algorithm would ever include an edge joining two stores) and likewise the distances between warehouses.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think that deserves to be an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: The technical term for this is the "bipartite traveling salesman problem," which turns up quite a lot of literature on the subject when Googled.

Comment: @Kevin make this a answer please

Comment: @Cornel: Stack Exchange policy is very clear: A search query is not an answer. I would have to pick one of those papers and write it up, and I lack both the technical knowledge and the institutional library access to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run a standard traveling salesman algorithm, setting the distances between stores to infinity (meaning: to such a large number that no self-respecting traveling salesman algorithm would ever include an edge joining two stores) and likewise the distances between warehouses.